# Using If/Else in Powershell, won't append out-file from Else command

Tags: powershell, if-statement, append, report

I'm using If/Else to use Remove-Item in powershell. When setting a variable to = one file, or folder, the "Else" will allow me to run

```
{Write-output "$FileName doesn't exist" | out-file -append "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestReports\TestReport.txt"}
```

However, when I set the variable to contain multiple files or folders ex. `$FileName = "*.bmp","*.docx","*.txt"` or `@("*.bmp","*.docx","*.txt")` the "Else" command will not run.

The only difference in the scripts is the multiple files set to $FileName.

```
$FileNames = @("C:\Users\username\Documents\ifTest1\*.bmp",
"C:\Users\username\Documents\ifTest1\*.docx",
"C:\Users\username\Documents\ifTest1\*.txt")

foreach ($i in $FileNames) {

if (Test-Path $FileNames) {

    Remove-Item $FileNames -force
    Write-output "$FileNames have been deleted" | out-file "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestReports\TestReport.txt"
}

else {

    Write-output "$FileNames don't exist" | out-file -append "C:\Users\username\Desktop\TestReports\TestReport.txt"
}
}
```

Comment: If you’re putting the value of ``$FilePath`` to an array, I’m pretty sure you need to wrap your ``if/else`` into a ``foreach`` loop. 

``foreach($file in $filepath){}``

Comment: @Fitzgery I've tried this. The If executes fine, but the Else won't run after the files have been deleted it will not -append the "$FileNames don't exist" text to the txt file.

Comment: Instead of using ``$filenames`` use ``$i``. That’s each item individually and should work

Comment: Because you are using wildcards in the filenames, you will delete **all** `.bmp`, `.docx` and `.txt` files in path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\ifTest1'. Is that really your goal? Do you want to add a line for every **individual** file in the TestReport.txt file?